# Meteor - Understanding template 'rendered' calls

Tags: meteor

I'm a bit of a newb in Meteor so this is possibly a trivial question for you Meteor masters out there.

I use a template which has a couple of child templates:

```
<template name="parent">
{{> child1}}
{{> child2}}
</template>
```

I noticed that *parent.rendered* and *child1.rendered* functions are invoked when reactive data under *child2* changes.
My understanding of meteor docs is that only *child2.rendered* should be called. So, what I am seeing should not happen, yet for a reason which is beyond me, it does.

To rule out any noise, I gutted the *child1* template (to contain only an empty div). Still, its rendered function is called.

Can anyone provide insight?

Answer (score 3):

As of Meteor 0.7.0.1, the parent template will be re-rendered but the sibling child templates will not.

Here is a simple example Meteor app that shows this in action:
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-subtemplate-isolate-test

Keep in mind that Meteor UI is getting a drastic overhaul before Meteor 1.0 lands so a lot of things may change with respect to how templating works.

Comment: That's a very useful example. Thanks for coming up with that. Still, in my example, the (empty div) sibling template does get rendered (in addition to the parent), which is different from the behavior in your app. I wonder what can cause it

Comment: There must be something triggering the invalidation (re-render).  Can you fork my `meteor-subtemplate-isolate-test` example and modify it so that it occurs there?  Then we can look further into why its happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just hypothesizing here, but I think the entire page rerenders when any reactive data changes. For example, if you were to have data in `Session.get('test')` and the only time the value of that is inserted into the DOM is in `child2`, I believe the entire page still rerenders.